# Optimize string search in .txt file

Tags: c++, sorting, search, optimization, text

This might be a really stupid question, but how do I optimize this code in making it more effiecient (faster,less memory consuming)? I made this code to help me sort some text files. It reads each string from the first file, then it searches through the second file until it finds all related strings, and in a third file it writes some matched strings. Here is the code:

```
ifstream h("SecondFile.txt");
ifstream h2("FirstFile.txt");
ifstream uh("MatchedStrings.txt");
ofstream g("sorted.txt");    
int main()
    {
        string x, y, z;
        cout << "Sorting..." << endl;;
        while (!h.eof()){
            h >> x;
            while (!h2.eof() || (y == x)){
                h2 >> y;
                uh >> z;
                if (y == x){
                    g << z << endl;
                    break;
                    h2.clear();
                    h2.seekg(0);
                    uh.clear();
                    uh.seekg(0);
                }
            }
            if (h2.eof() && (y != x)){
                g << "none" << endl;
                h2.clear();
                h2.seekg(0);
                uh.clear();
                uh.seekg(0);
            }
        }
        cout << "Finished!";
    }
```

I have changed my code to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
ifstream h("SecondFile.txt");
ifstream h2("FirstFile.txt");
ifstream uh("MatchedStrings.txt");
ofstream g("sorted.txt");

int main()
{
    string x;
    bool write_none = true;
    int i = 0,l=0;
    string check[] = {""};
    string unhashed_checked[] = { "" };
    string sorted_array[] = { "" };
    cout << "Sorting..." << endl;
    //Get to memory
    while (!h2.eof())
    {
        h2 >> check[i];
        uh >> unhashed_checked[i];
        i++;
    }

    while (!h.eof()){
        h >> x;
        write_none = true;
        for (int t = 0; t <= i;t++)
        {
            if (x == check[t])
            {
                break;
                write_none = false;
                sorted_array[l] = unhashed_checked[i];
                l++;
            }
        }
        if (write_none)
        {
            sorted_array[l] = "none";
            l++;
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k <= l; k++)
    {
        g << sorted_array[k]<<endl;
    }
    cout << "Finished!";
}
```

But I am getting this exception when running the program:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x01068FF6 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC
```

Comment: It would probably be faster to collect all of the search strings from the 1st file in memory, and use these in the outer loop to search the 2nd file.

Comment: I will try that and come back with the results.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can't get it to work :/ I have tried reading it into memory but getting an unhandled exception 0xccccccc

Comment: Do as @Ilya said, use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Why are all your streams global? You only have a single function anyway! Also, without the files, it's impossible to reproduce the issue. Further, is the input from the files even necessary to reproduce the issue? Try to extract a minimal but complete example first!

Comment: Those "breaks" are unfortunately placed.

Comment: @Jongware 1: "belongs to CodeReview" is not a reason for closing as off-topic. 2: The OP says he gets an exception, hence this is not working code.

Comment: @Caridorc: well the OP himself broke working code by trying to optimize it. So perhaps he could post only the first (working!) part there. (I disagree on your #1; Stack Overflow is for not-working code, Code Review is for working code - per the [Help/on-topic].)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the number of strings in your files are *n* and *m*, respectively.

The way you're doing it now, the complexity is *Θ(n m)*. Moreover, the complexity constants are those of file operations, which are incredibly slow.

Instead, you should just read one of the files into a [`std::unordered_*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) container, then compare keys between the containers. This should reduce the running time to expected *Θ(n + m)*.

---

As a side note, you might want to look at [more modern ways to read strings into containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/100055/) (using, e.g., [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)).

Comment: There's also a "memory-consuming" part in the question. If one of the files is very big, you might not want to load it in a memory container.

Comment: @Ilya thanks, corrected. I also now see that you've addressed that in an answer of yours (+1). I would recommend using the `unordered_*` container here, though.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the `std::unordered_set`, learned something, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your support.I got it to work using that example you gave me.

Answer (score 4):

Load `h` in a vector of strings, and loop once through `h2` by comparing each string with the vector's contents.

Since your test is symmetrical, you can choose `h` to be the smallest of the two files. That way, you'll save memory and time, especially if one of the files is much larger than the other. Using a set (`std::set`) instead of a vector could also help if the comparisons are costing a significant time.